# Changing a TGV booking

Tags: trains, france

I have a TGV train booked from Gare Montparnasse to Rennes. There is 12 days left to travel. Now I want to change the booking from CDG airport to Rennes on that same day i.e., I want to change the boarding station.

Do I need to pay charge for this change and if so, how much ?

Comment: How did you book it? Can you look it up online?

Comment: @Relaxed, i have booked online and paid

Comment: If you booked it directly from SNCF, you should be able to modify it yourself on https://www.oui.sncf/monvoyage/recherche using its reference number.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends on your fare, some TGV tickets can be changed, some can be changed for a small fee up to two days before travel, others yet cannot or not without a hefty fee. If your fare allows it and seats are available, it could be possible to change the date and time without additional fee.

Additionally, there are very few TGV from CDG to Rennes (one a day, I think), perhaps a handful of possible TGV connections. Most of the time, the train connections shown use local transit (RER) to reach Montparnasse. If you want to do that, you could also keep your current ticket and just buy a local transit ticket separately. Do budget some additional time to navigate the Paris local transportation network (especially if you have a lot of luggage).

But @MaxJasper's suggestion is also well worth considering: Le Bus Direct is somewhat more expensive but a lot less hassle in this case as it would bring you directly to the train station from the airport without the need to figure out a local transit connection.

The airport website provides [additional info on the various ways to reach Paris from CDG](https://www.parisaeroport.fr/en/passengers/access/paris-charles-de-gaulle/public-transport), with links to buy tickets when available.

Comment: can i buy local transit ticket online now  in advance?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Apparently it's possible: https://www.parisaeroport.fr/en/passengers/services/book-a-service/transport-to-and-from-the-airport More info on the various option on https://www.parisaeroport.fr/en/passengers/access/paris-charles-de-gaulle/public-transport

Answer (score 12):

Don't waste your time and a lot of money to change your TGV ticket. At CDG jump on Les BusDirect #4 for 17€ and get off at Montparnass Gare and board your TGV to Rennes without hassle. Bon voyages.

Les Bus Direct [enter link description here](https://www.lebusdirect.com/en/)

Comment: (+1) Great option, I missed line 4 when I looked up the airport page earlier!

Comment: My sister used to live at Montparnasse, I've taken that bus many times and highly recommend it as the least hassle

Comment: I think it's more commonly known as Gare Montparnasse.

Answer (score 8):

The train from Montparnasse to Rennes and the train from Charles de Gaulle to Rennes are different trains, so you are looking to change the booking entirely.

Depending on the ticket type you booked, you may be able to get a refund on the original ticket and book a new one.

If it is "Modifiable sous conditions", then you should be able to get a refund (minus €5) until the day before departure.

Answer (score 5):

You need to change your ticket, this can be done online if you have an e-ticket, the penalty ammount will be displayed there:

> A exchange quote will be displayed together with any penalties.
>   On validation, a confirmation email will be sent to the email address you provided during exchange.
>   After completing your ticket exchange online, you will be redirected to our search page to select your next journey.

([Reference](https://en.oui.sncf/en/help-en/exchange-train-ticket))

If you don't have an e-ticket:

**The booking is less than €200:**

> After exchanging your ticket online on “My Bookings”, send your refund request (within 60 days) via our contact form 
>   Specify your request by selecting “Train Journey” then “Follow-up Request”. Lastly, fill in the following information in the “My Message ” section:
>
> - Your surname and first names
> - Your contact details
> - The reason for your request
>
> To complete your request, attach a photo of the ticket you wish to exchange. The ticket should be cut in two as seen in the example below.  All important details must be visible in order to proceed with the refund.
>
> **Example of attached file:** 
>   [image: example[2]]

**The booking is more than €200:**

> After exchanging your ticket online on “ My Bookings”, send your refund request (within 60 days) via our contact form:
>
> SNCF
>   Service Clientèle
>   62973 ARRAS Cedex 9
>   France
>
> Include the following supporting documents with your request :
>
> - The original travel cards (please be aware no copies will be accepted!)
> - The reason for your request with your surname, first name and contact details.